# group sql results by substring

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table with some records where a column represents the group of every record:

```
id  | group
1     abc_xxx
2     abc_yyy
3     def_ooo
4     def_ppp
5     ghi_jjj
6     ghi_kkk
```

When I do a query and group the rows by the group column, I get

```
abc_xxx
abc_yyy
def_ooo
def_ppp
ghi_jjj
ghi_kkk
```

However it's not the correct output that I need, I need to get instead something like that:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Because it represents the real classification  of the records under the group column. So I'm looking for a method in SQL Server 2005 with which I can get that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) or [LEFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) (which is simpler but non-standard):

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING([group], 1, 3) AS [group]
FROM table
GROUP BY 
    SUBSTRING([group], 1, 3)
```

Or,

```
SELECT
    LEFT([group], 3) AS [group]
FROM table
GROUP BY 
    LEFT([group], 3)
```

When grouping it's usually to aggregate something, so I'm guessing you're looking for something like:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING([group], 1, 3) AS [group],
    COUNT(*) AS [count]
FROM table
GROUP BY 
    SUBSTRING([group], 1, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use SUBSTRING() in your select?  Refer to MSDN [SUBSTRING() Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.groupcode
FROM
  (SELECT id, group, left(group,charindex('_',group)-1) as groupcode FROM table) t
GROUP BY
  groupcode
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(col, 1, CHARINDEX('_', col) -1)
FROM kittens
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `left` to extract the group `prefix`:

```
SELECT LEFT([group], 3) AS grp
FROM table
GROUP BY LEFT([group], 3);
```

Note: Please try to avoid using reserved keywords for column names: e.g. `group`